# Label Targets Expander

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a label with this content: `Fol_Der` (Folder with the d underlined for an Alt shortcut).

The element it is targeting is an Expander.

My goal is that when the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> the Expander will expand.

However all I get when it is pressed is a dashed outline:

[image: Dashed expander]

How can I target it properly so it would expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define a command

```
public static RoutedUICommand ExpandFolderCommand{ get; private set; }

 ExpandFolderCommand= new RoutedUICommand("ExpandFolderCommand", "ExpandFolderCommand", typeof(Commands),       new InputGestureCollection { 
                    new KeyGesture(Key.D, ModifierKeys.Alt, "Alt+D") });
```

then define your command binding in your Window/UserControl

```
 <UserControl.CommandBindings>
          <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static ExpandFolderCommand}"
                          Executed="ExpandFolderCommand_Executed" 
                          CanExecute="ExpandFolderCommand_CanExecute"/>
 </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

the ExpandFolderCommand_Executed should expand your expander

for further reading [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

Comment: Ah, I suspected targeting wouldn't end up being the solution. Thanks.